# Low Level Speech Recognition in iOS

Tags: ios, machine-learning, speech-recognition

From what I have seen online, Apple dev APIs enable use of speech recognition but only at a very high level.

Is there a way to access low-level speech recognition tools, so that for example, the speech can be used to recognize a particular individual or determine the mood of speaker? Of course, these would require bespoke algorithms, but I am asking whether or not the data would be available.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that distinguishing voices or moods is any lower-level than generic speech recognition.

Comment: A part of the question is whether or not you could access the low level tools that determine text from speech, and that it does not just spit a string of text right back at you..@PatrickRoberts